# How to pass entire HashMap in Dozer mapping ?

Tags: spring-el, dozer

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>java.util.Map</class-a>
    <class-b>class</class-b>
    <field custom-converter="some custom convertor">
        <a>this</a>
        <b>anotherField</b>
        <a-hint>java.util.Map</a-hint>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

When I'm trying to pass this entire HashMap in my custom convertor, it is coming as null.

```
   @Override
   public Object convert(Object existingDestinationFieldValue, Object   sourceFieldValue,
                            Class<?> destinationClass, Class<?>  sourceClass) {
   // sourcefield is coming as NULL. 
   }
```

Any other way can we pass the entire Map for Custom Convertor, other than passing it as "this"?